# Convert the python code into a graphical flowchart

Tags: python, python-3.x

just wondering if there is some free and easy way to convert the python code into a graphical flowchart image?

or maybe some method or module or something else to get output in textual description near to flowchart by comments as it was done earlier in pascal

```
process 
    keys by comments
condition 
    keys by comments
process
    keys by comments
condition
```

Comment: Similar to this question : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4468364/graph-rendering-in-python-flowchart-visualization

Comment: I don't think this is a duplicate of the sited question. Its not asking how to create a graph USING python code, it's asking how to make a graph OF python code.