# How to create a visualization of nested ifelse loop as a decision tree in python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, decision-tree

I have a nested ifelse loop like below

```
if var1 >0:
    if var2>0:
        print(var1, var2)
    else var2<0:
        print(var1, var2)
else:
    if var2>0:
        print(var1, var2)
    else var2<0:
        print(var1, var2)
```

I want to visualize it as a tree. Is there any library or workaround to visualize it?

Comment: This is a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4468364/graph-rendering-in-python-flowchart-visualization, a popular question that was closed as off-topic.